# getting information for the existing docker containers

Tags: docker

I am running a docker image using the following command:

```
sudo docker run -it -v "${pwd}:/qc/output" qc
```

It works perfectly then I used the following command to get the list of existing docker containers

```
sudo docker ps --filter ancestor=ubuntu
```

but it returns only headers which is the following line:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

do you know why it is empty and how I can get the information for the existing docker containers?

Comment: is the image still running when you run the `ps` command?

Comment: does it show up when you run `sudo docker ps -a` ?

Comment: `ancestor=ubuntu` => are you running an image built on ubuntu ? From the test I just made, you should add the tag for this to work (i.e. `ubuntu:18.04`). What does a simple `docker ps` says ?

Answer (score 0):

you will get all running containers details by command

`docker ps`

use `docker ps -a` to see all active and non-active container details